# Django logging on windows -- don't think RotatingFileHandler is going to work for me

Tags: django, windows, logging

I'm developing an intranet-type application in Django for an organization who requires that my hosting machine be running windows.

There are [known issues](https://bugs.python.org/issue4749) with python's RotatingFileHandler and windows. Specifically, when multiple processes are logging, you run in to issues when rolling the files over:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\logging\handlers.py", line 77, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\logging\handlers.py", line 142, in doRollover
    os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

There is a [replacement log handler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ConcurrentLogHandler) but it has some dependencies I don't want to deal with.

I need to be able to log from multiple processes because I'm running a bunch of commands from `manage.py` periodically via cron. How do people typically handle logging with Django on Windows? It seems like my use case is probably fairly common.